# Copy of the Sukti Sudhakar

Tags: scripture, bhakti, reference-request

I tried searching online for an English copy of the *Sukti Sudhakar*, but I could only find Hindi copies. Can anyone provide a link to an English version (or a Sanskrit to English version) of this book? I also tried searching for this book on hinduscriptures.com but could not find it. Since my knowledge of hinduscriptures.com is limited, can anyone tell me if this book can be found in that website? If so, in what part of the website can I find it?

Thanks